# ColdFusion unable to read FormData sent by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, coldfusion, jquery-file-upload

I'm creating a file upload component that I can `<cfinclude>` onto any of my CFM pages which allows for both the standard file selection and Drag & Drop functionality.

When **choosing** a file and submitting the form, there is no problem since my ColdFusion code relies on the Form scope in order to retrieve the file.

In order to send files using the Drag & Drop feature, I'm using jQuery to send a request through Ajax sending the `FormData` based on the current form.

```
$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get FormData based on form and append the dragged and dropped files 
    var ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0));
    if (droppedFiles) {
        $.each(droppedFiles, function(i, file) {
            ajaxData.append($('input[type=file]').attr('name'), file);
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        cache: false,
        contentType:false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.SUCCESS) uploadSuccessful($form);
            else
            {
                console.error(data.ERROR);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error('Error: File upload unsuccessful ' + errorThrown);
        },
        data: ajaxData,
        dataType: 'json',
        dataFilter: function(data, type){ 
            return data.substring(2, data.length); 
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML:

```
<form class="file-upload-container" method="post" action="upload.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label class="file-upload-input">
        <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:5em;"></i><br/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
    </label>
    <div class="file-upload-controls">
        <input type="button" id="cancelUpload" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-green" />
        <input type="submit" id="upload" value="Upload" class="btn btn-green" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The `action` of the `<form>` is to post to my **upload.cfm** page.

I first verify if the form posted had a element with the name "attachment":

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "attachment")>
    <!--- This always passes since I'm posting the form with the submit button --->
</cfif>
```

I then try to retrieve the filename so I can compare against the accepted file types, upload the file, rename the file, and insert an entry into my database. Where I am experiencing my issue is when I'm trying to get the filename from the posted `FormData` object (or even the entire File's contents..).

```
<cffunction name="GetTheFileName" access="public" returntype="string" output="false" >
    <cfargument name="fieldName" required="true" type="string" hint="Name of the Form field" />

    <cfset var tmpPartsArray = Form.getPartsArray() />

    <cfif IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")>
        <cfloop array="#tmpPartsArray#" index="local.tmpPart">
            <cfif local.tmpPart.isFile() AND local.tmpPart.getName() EQ arguments.fieldName> 
                <cfreturn LCase(local.tmpPart.getFileName()) />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfreturn "" />
</cffunction>
```

The line `Form.getPartsArray()` returns an array, however the values within the array are empty. (e.g., FilePath:'',FileName:'')

This leads me to believe that `FormData` doesn't act in the same way as an actual form that is posted, regardless if ajax is posting the `FormData` as multipart/form-data.

### Questions

1. What am I missing in order to read the `FormData` object on the ColdFusion side in order to retrieve the FileName.
2. How can the Form scope effectively utilize posted `FormData` as if it were an actual `<form>` being posted.

### Research

This [source](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/08/uploading-chunks-of-large-file-using.html) indicates that I can read the file using Java's FileOutputStream. *(Not an ideal solution since I also allow for the typical "Choose a file" which already utilizes the Form scope)*

Comment: What is `form` in `new FormData($(form).get(0))`? Either it should be `$form.get(0)` or simply `this` -> `new FormData(this)`

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry about that, I reorganized code by copy pasting for functions. I'll correct it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be handling the files using cffile with action='upload'? Also, in your $.each on droppedFiles, what is `input`?

Comment: I suggest making your function more pure by only relying on data that is passed to it as arguments.  That mean you don't use the form scope in your function.

Comment: @KevinB I am using cffile with action="upload" however I need to verify that the extension of the file matches against a list of extensions that I allow on top of the mime type. As for the "input", I forgot to add the input in my example above. I'll correct the description.

Comment: @MPaul Mime type can be easily spoofed. Watch out.

Comment: @Shawn I'm using both the file extension and the mime type as validations before uploading, however you bring up a good point. What else can be done on this front other than running an anti-virus on the destination folder?

Comment: @MPaul Upload your file to an off-site location, like Amazon S3. If you have to do it on your system, don't upload to a web-accessible location. Set permissions on that folder to the minimum required. Especially watch out for Execute permissions. Don't let the user specify the filename. https://www.petefreitag.com/item/701.cfm This is an old (but sadly still applicable) article, and Pete has some great suggestions. (He has other great security tips, too.)

Comment: @Shawn Excellent, thanks. I've verified and I've already applied the suggestions you listed (except for the off-site location)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution, albeit not the solution I was initially hoping for.

From my observations, ColdFusion does not treat the `FormData` object in the same way as an actual form post. This is clear when the Form scope doesn't contain the form data.

Instead I had to handle data posted with the Drag & Drop functionality in a different manner.

Following the suggested method for uploading chunks of files ([source](http://www.sagarganatra.com/2012/08/uploading-chunks-of-large-file-using.html)), I requested the `upload.cfm` page through ajax where the Content-Type matched the MimeType of the file to be uploaded, and the actual upload used the `java.io.FileOutputStream` class to write the file to disk.

JavaScript + AJAX:

```
var droppedFiles; // Assuming droppedFiles was populated during the 'drop' event

// Get the Form and FormData (although FormData won't be used when files are Dragged  & Dropped)
var $form = $('.file-upload-container');
var ajaxData = new FormData($(form).get(0));

var dragged = false;                
var filesToBeUploaded = document.getElementById("attachment");  
var file = filesToBeUploaded.files[0]; 
if (droppedFiles){file = droppedFiles;dragged=true;}

$.ajax({
    url: $form.attr('action'),
    type: $form.attr('method'),
    cache: false,
    contentType: dragged ? file.type : false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.SUCCESS) { // Do stuff }
        else
        {
            // Do stuff
            console.error(data.ERROR);
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: File upload unsuccessful ' + errorThrown);
    },
    data: dragged ? file : ajaxData,
    dataType: 'json',
    dataFilter: function(data, type){ 
        return data.substring(2, data.length); 
    },
    headers: { 'X_FILE_NAME': dragged ? file.name : "", 'X_CONTENT_TYPE': dragged ? file.type : "" }
});
```

ColdFusion:

```
<cfset bUseFormData = false />

<cfset headerData = getHTTPRequestData().headers>
<cfif structKeyExists(headerData, "X_FILE_NAME") AND ("#headerData.X_FILE_NAME#" NEQ "")>
    <cfset bUseFormData = true />        
</cfif>

<cfif structKeyExists(form, "attachment") OR bUseFormData>

    <cfif bUseFormData>
        <cfset content = getHTTPRequestData().content>
        <cfset filePath = "#Application.AdminUploadPath#\" & "#headerData.X_CONTENT_TYPE#">
        <cfset fos = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(filePath, true)>
        <cfset fos.write(content)>
        <cfset fos.close()>
    <cfelse>
        <cffile action="UPLOAD" filefield="form.attachment" destination="#Application.AdminUploadPath#">
    </cfif>

</cfif>
```

*For simplicity's sake, I've excluded code validating file extension, MimeType, and error handling.*